# WCF issues - line not reached

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf

I have a WCF service library, name ServerWCF, which contains a "AdminService" service. One of the methods of this service is List LoadStation() which should return a List of train stations from my database.

I also have a WPF Client, and I'm using a dropdown that should contain the Cities of the stations. When I added the Service Reference in the client, named AdminServiceReference, i noticed that the signature of the method is Station[] Load Station() instead on ListLoadStation(). I don't know if I can do anything about this as the code is generated automatically in the client, but whatever(I used the resharper refactoring suggestion, but didn't make any difference). The problem is that on the below code, the foreach line is never accessed. I placed a breakpoint on the line above, I stepped into and noticed that the list returned by the Server contains all of the station, which is a good thing, but after i step out and step over, the program is not going to the foreach that populates the dropdown, but returns to the second line, which is the reason why, obviously, my dropdown remains empty, lonely and sad :( Any tip on how can i sort this out? PS: that same code worked fine when my list was a ArrayList and was containing only Cities, but I need all the objects.

Client code:

```
private void fromStationCB_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var adminProxy = new AdminServiceClient();
            fromStationCB.Items.Clear();
            var list = adminProxy.LoadStations();
            foreach (var items in list)
                fromStationCB.Items.Add(items.City);
            label5.Content = "";
        }
```

Server code:

```
public List<Station> LoadStations()
        {
            List<Station> list = new List<Station>();
            using (var context = new RailwaySystemModelContainer())
            {
                /*foreach (var station in context.Stations)
                    list.Add(station);*/
                list.AddRange(context.Stations);
                return list;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Post your Station class definition please.

Comment: @YawarMurtaza, please see it here: https://pastebin.com/SQrJbapD

Comment: All my class have been generated by the Entity Framework, as I used the Design First approach

Comment: I have read your comment from the answer below that you have already decorated your Station class with DataContract and its properties with DataMember so thats taken care of, however, the linked you posted doesnt show that which i can safely assume that its an older version of Station class. If you could put a break point on "var list = adminProxy.LoadStations();" and step through and see whats in the list object? Alternatively, you can wrap the call to wcf method into a try-catch mathod and see if any exception is thrown? I would also like to see the binding configuration if possible please.

Comment: @YawarMurtaza, please help me understand a thing... I have done that: https://pastebin.com/B74e1Ay6 in the IAdminService. Do I need to change the proprieties of the Station class as well?

Comment: I have used a CUI in order to debug as well and I get the following error message: https://s2.postimg.org/99ry3q0uh/error.png

Comment: IAdminService is your service contract. You also need to declare the data contract which is your Station class. Please decorate your Station class with DataContract and its all properties with DataMember attribute. From the error message it looks like there is a missmatch in the bindings config.

Comment: I see, I will do that and will confirm once done. I feel stupid now, but in the same time my project does a lot of other things. Now I realize that in the other cases, the Service was returning only a string to confirm if the insert in the database was done or not

Comment: We all come here to learn and share our knowledge and experience so dont feel bad by asking questions.

Comment: Thanks! I have an issue with adding the [DataMember] to the constructor of the Passenger class: https://s22.postimg.org/ucm5iyza9/Data_Member.png

Comment: Is required to the added to the constructors or not?

Comment: DataMember attribute is only applied to the properties, DataContract will be aaplied to the class. What is this Passenger class you never mentioned this before? try this link to see how DataMember and DataContract attributes are used. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/576820/Basic-Step-by-Step-WCF-WebService

Comment: @YawarMurtaza, is not important, the Passenger is a subclass of the User class. It's not relevant to my problem, as it's not used as all in this context.I managed to add all the data contracts to the classes and datamember to the proprieties & methods. I will remove the datamemember from the methods then

Comment: Why do you have methods in a DataContract class? It is against the WCF best prectice however, its not illegal to do so. DataContract classes are just a POCO objects that travel acorss the wire to and from the WCF service. Please keem them simple POCO objects and thats what they should be. I am thinking to write a sample code for you and will post it on githiub later this evening. Will post the link here.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, in fact i don't, my brain is destroyed.

Comment: I made a confusion with the fact that I have methods in the service

Comment: @YawarMurtaza I have like this: Station class: https://pastebin.com/BUW41pF4  IAdminService: https://pastebin.com/y0sQDAvJ  AdminService: https://pastebin.com/8AAm3rct   NavAdmin Window from Client: https://pastebin.com/p3N0wSQ3 . The issue is with the  private void fromStationCB_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e) in the client(line 139)

Comment: I have the project here, if you want to have a closer look: https://www.dropbox.com/s/u7902oru761tkla/RailwaySystemBeta%20-%20Copy.zip?dl=0

Comment: I have downloaded and edited your project. My edited version is on GITHUB https://github.com/Yawarmurtaza/RailwaySystemBeta---Copy that you can download. I have added 2 new console based projects, 1st to host WCF service with the net.tcp binding and other as console based client app that consumes IAdminService service contract. When you have downloaded the zip file, just extract it and open in VS2017/15 and run these 2 projects: RailwayServiceConsoleHost and RailwayService.ConsoleClient. The client now gets the list of stations.

Comment: @YawarMurtaza, wow, that is great, although I don't understand why the server needs a console app to be hosted? I thought that the server is started together with the client? Need to do some more research on this matter...also, I noticed that you allStation is a list that you provided fixed values, when I uncommented that and used the values from my database, no values were returned :-s

Comment: Yes i have hard-coded these values just to narrow down the problem area. If you are not getting any stations from the database then its not WCF issue and I would recommend you to post another question. WCF can be hosted on any executable and the simplest way in the development mode its best to use a console host. Once you are happy with it, you can host it as windows service or on IIS. Im glad to know that you have finally a working solution as far as WCF is concern.

Comment: Ok, will do, you helped me a lot, thank you very much :)

Comment: @YawarMurtaza, I managed to fix the problem, it seems like when adding to the list, i should've put new Station(): https://pastebin.com/ddyCErJv  I will try this on my original project, it might work. Please let me know if I can give you reputation or something for your great help :)

Comment: Not much can be done in these comments to with respect to the reputations. At the end of the day we all come here to share our knowledge and I'm glad that you have a working solution. I would like to assume that your trust on this community has also increased.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems when using list as a return type. It was something different, but you can try change the return type of `LoadStations` to an array of Station. Also try delete your reference, build the server side code and then add the reference again. You can have some mismatch. Also `Station` should be marked as a `DataContract` and its properties as `DataMember` to successfully pass it via service.

Comment: The station is marked as DataContract and the proprieties as DataMember. As I said, i've done this when I passed only city name as string, but I need the Station now. I tried with Station[] as well, rebuild the server& client, re added the reference, debugged the code, the array has all the vaues, but when i step over, does not go to the foreach, but returns to the beginning of the method

Comment: And then it goes where? it is doing entire method again or jump to the end?

Comment: it goes back to the first line where it clears the combobox :(

Comment: in fact, the wpf window pops in without letting me see what happens in the foreach or if that is reached or not.